# How to retrieve Status of each test cases in TestRail via Webhook?

Tags: webhooks, slack, testrail

Anyone has experience using TestRail? I am trying to use this payload webhook with Slack and each time when I update my test case, the status is always null. How can i make sure it reads properly (ie Passed, Failed, Disabled)

[image]

[image]

```
   {
      "text": "%event_creator% created a new test case:",
      "blocks": [
        {
          "type": "section",
          "text": {
            "type": "mrkdwn",
            "text": "*%event_creator% created a new test case:*"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "divider"
        },
        {
          "type": "section",
          "text": {
            "type": "mrkdwn",
            "text": "*<%url%|%name%>* \n Priority: %case_priority% \n Status: %stats%"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not give you passed or failed using %stats% variable unfortunately but rather it will give you count of each status in Test Results event. You need to check Test Result(s) created so when a user updates the test result then it will only show you the result of that test run.

Your example script will pull only if the correct event you have selected is what you have triggered.

Best is you use the UI Script feature where you can paste the UI Script from test rail github and it would create a button in Test Run View page and then you can send results to Slack Channel.

[Public TestRail customizations GitHub repository.](https://github.com/gurock/testrail-custom/tree/master/user-submitted/ui-scripts)

You may find a script which already suits your needs or which only needs a few simple changes.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e389O.png)